# Memcached + batch data loading + replication + load balancing, any existing solutions?

Tags: c#, windows, database, memcached, hashtable

Here is my scenario:

A dozen of clients reading from memcached-like store.

- Read-only access
- 50K gets/sec
- 99.999% availability
- 300 million records, 100 bytes each

If one of the stores goes down the system should be able to automatically switch to another replica. When it is time for update the system should be able to quickly reload data without affecting clients.

Is there existing solution to satisfy these requirements? I already evaluated memcached, velocity, and reviewed bunch of other projects ([anti-rdbms-a-list-of-distributed-key-value-stores](http://www.metabrew.com/article/anti-rdbms-a-list-of-distributed-key-value-stores/)). I would prefer something that runs on Windows x64, but wouldn't shy away from *nix if there is something that would support my requirements out of the box. Paid products are OK. Quality is very important, can't rely on half-baked betas.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Velocity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/cc655792.aspx). Right now it is CTP 3, so it may or may not violate your half-baked betas requirement. Check out their blog for perf numbers. Looks promising.

Comment: I already tried Velocity. After two hours of fighting with various issues I had to abandon it. This release doesn't seem to be even near beta product quality... no way I would put it in production